# C#: Properly using WeakReference IsAlive property

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, weak-references

As explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.isalive(v=vs.110).aspx), if `WeakReference`'s `IsAlive` returns true, then it cannot be trusted. Now, I'm trying to understand the [correct way](https://csharp.2000things.com/2012/12/13/735-dont-trust-weakreference-isalive-if-it-returns-true/) to use this:

Incorrect:

```
WeakReference dogRef = new WeakReference(dog);

// Later, try to ref original Dog

if (dogRef.IsAlive)
{
    // Oops - garbage collection on original Dog could occur here
    ((Dog)dogRef.Target).Bark();
}
```

Correct:

```
WeakReference dogRef = new WeakReference(dog);

// Later, try to ref original Dog

Dog origDog = (Dog)dogRef.Target;
if (origDog != null)
{
    origDog.Bark();
}
```

My question is, is there any difference from the point of view of the GC, between `if(origDog != null` and `dogRef.Target != null`? Suppose, I did not need to invoke methods of the `Dog` class but just needed to check if the target was alive. Should I always cast the target to a class instance or is it okay to check `Target` against null?

I ask this because I want to execute some logic if the object is alive that does not involve the object itself.

Comment: Maybe it's better if you describe in more detail what is your goal. You check if object is alive but don't do anything with it. It can be GCed at any point later. What would you do with this info?

Comment: @Evk That's a good point. The existing design is using a `Tuple<WeakReference, Action<int>>`. The idea is to execute the action only if the first object is alive.

Comment: The object should be alive until at least the action finishes. So I wasn't sure if I should hold a local reference to it and then execute the action or just check `Target` against null and execute the action.

Comment: But would be better to pass that object itself into Action if it depends on it. This at least will make design and intention cleaner to my mind.

Comment: I think this might be a breaking change, so I'm not sure if that's an option at the moment. If comparing `Target` with null obtains a strong reference until the end of the scope, I think that's all I needed to know. I wasn't exactly sure if a local variable was needed.

Comment: But how that Action itself will obtain reference to that object (since it should be alive I guess it uses target object somehow)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is, is there any difference from the point of view of the GC, between if(origDog != null and dogRef.Target != null?

With `origDog` then if `origDog` is not null (because there was indeed a reference when `dogRef.Target` was assigned to it, then it will continue to not be null until it is either written over, or becomes collectable.

With `dogRef.Target != null` then problem isn't that call — it will work fine — but with the time in between that and the attempt to use it.

(Incidentally, while it's more typing, as a rule creating a temporary value on the stack instead of hitting a property twice is generally going to be slightly more efficient. It's not so much more efficient that to make it worth doing when calling the property is more natural to type, but it is worth noting if the only reason for not wanting to create the temporary `dogRef` was fear that it was extra work for the application).

From a comment:

> If comparing Target with null obtains a strong reference until the end of the scope

It doesn't, and nor does assigning. It's important to realise that scope has nothing to do with collectability. In the code:

```
void SomeMethodWhichThereforeHasAScope()
{
  Dog origDog = (Dog)dogRef.Target;
  if (origDog != null)
  {
    Console.Write(dogRef.Target == null); // probably going to be false (though sometimes reads get reordered, so there's a chance that happens).
    origDog.Bark();
  }

  Console.Write(dogRef.Target == null); // could be true or false
  var sb = new StringBuilder("I'm a string that got referenced in a call to a method");
  Console.Write(sb.ToString());
  Console.Write(dogRef.Target == null); // even more likely to be true.
}
```

`origDog` is in scope at the time of the third test of `Target` but it isn't used after it. Which means the reference to the object on the stack and/or in a register that was used to invoke `Bark` may have been used for something else (more likely the more work has happened in the method), which means that if the GC kicks in it may not find a reference.

"Scope" is about where you *can* use a variable. The GC works based on where you *did* use it. Once you've stopped using it, the GC might reclaim objects it referenced. Normally we don't care, because we don't use something after we use it (ipso facto) so we won't notice. Having another reference that goes through `WeakReference` changes that though.

This is why `GC.KeepAlive()` exists. It doesn't actually do anything, it's just a method that won't be optimised away so that if the only reason you want to keep a variable in scope is that some unusual GC stuff (`WeakReference` fits into the category of "unusual GC stuff") means you might want to use the same object through something other than that variable, it won't be collected until after that `KeepAlive()` call.

> Suppose, I did not need to invoke methods of the Dog class but just needed to check if the target was alive. Should I always cast the target to a class instance or is it okay to check Target against null?

Checking it's not null is fine. Indeed using `IsAlive` is fine. The problem with `IsAlive` is purely that it may become `false` at some point in the future. This is true for any means of checking on life.

(The only time I ever saw Luciano Pavarotti he was alive. I have not seen him since. The fact that he was perfectly alive the last time I saw him does not stop him being dead now. `WeakReference.IsAlive` is exactly the same).

Incidentally, for single calls the following is valid and convenient:

```
((Dog)dogRef.Target)?.Bark();
```

Because the `?.` operator will `dup` the reference so it's akin to:

```
var temp = ((Dog)dogRef.Target)
if (temp != null)
  temp.Bark();
```

So it's safe.

If there is a disconnect between the object and the work you will do you can use:

```
var temp = dogRef.Target;
if (temp != null)
{
   DoStuffHere();
   GC.KeepAlive(temp); // temp cannot be collected until this returns.
}
```

As said above, `KeepAlive()` is just a no-operation method that the compiler and jitter are not allowed to optimise away. As such there has to be a reference on the stack or in a register to pass to it, and the GC will see that and not collect it.

Comment: So then, how to achieve what OP wants? He wants to call some Action (which does not belong to the target object of weak reference), and ensure that during calling that Action reference target is still alive (he does not pass reference to that object to Action either).

Comment: Ah, the problem with important details in easily missed comments. WIll update.

Comment: +1 for `"Scope" is about where you can use a variable. The GC works based on where you did use it`. I think the last snippet makes a lot of sense. Thanks both for your assistance!

Comment: What do you mean by saying that assigning won't obtain a strong reference until the end of the scope? What holds the object from being collected between the null check and the method call? Isn't it the local variable 'origDog' that holds a reference to the Dog object? And that variable is still referencing Dog object when the third test of Target is executed hence keeping Dog alive, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of `IsAlive` is not to let code know when it's safe to use a `WeakReference`, but rather to check whether a reference has died off yet without any possibility of keeping it alive needlessly.

If code wants to use the target of a `WeakReference`, it must copy that to a variable and then check whether it's null; if the assignment occurs before the reference dies, the copy of the target stored in the variable will keep the reference alive.  The danger with using `if (weakref.Target == null) handleObjectDeath();` is that if no reference other reference exists to the target but the above code occurs just as a GC cycle is about to start, the GC might hold off on collecting the object (and invalidating the weak reference) because of the temporary reference returned by the `Target` property.  Using the `IsAlive` property avoids that risk.